# HTTP header disallowed characters?

Tags: spring-boot, http, https

I am trying to redirect my browser to a local html file via a SpringBoot app controller. When I attempt to do this, I received the following error:

```
 Note: further occurrences of HTTP request parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in the request target. The valid characters are defined in RFC 7230 and RFC 3986
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:467)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:294)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:836)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1747)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
```

with url:
`https://localhost:8443/green?file=C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Temp\green5833176921243123170.html`

The full method:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/green")
@SessionScope
@CrossOrigin
public class GreenController {

    @Autowired
    private GreenGenerationService greenGenerationService;
    
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GreenController.class);
    
    @PostMapping("")
    public String createGreenScreens(@RequestBody String swag) throws Exception {
        
        logger.info("Received request to create green screens");
        logger.info(swag);

        //green = C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Temp\green5833176921243123170.html
        String green = greenGenerationService.createGreenScreens(swag);

        logger.info("Created green screens: " + green);
        
        return green;//error with http headers?
        
    }
```

The above error is thrown when redirecting from the SpringBoot application. However,
when I put just `green5833176921243123170.html` into my browser, it successfully locates the file and redirects with no problem.

What is causing this error, and how does one fix this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have to encode the string, otherwise there are characters that are not allowed in a URL (for example   -> `%20`), so please try with this URL

```
C%3A%5CUsers%5Cmyuser%5CAppData%5CLocal%5CTemp%5Cgreen5833176921243123170.html
```

Comment: Thanks - is there an easy way to encode urls? I don't know what "encoding" actually means (pretty new to REST apis & HTTP protocol).

Secondly, is there a way to tell google that we are using an encoded url?

Comment: @Matthew for the sake of this question, I've used https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/, for "code" you can use `URLEncoder.encode(query, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);`